# remove www and html while forcing https

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

How would i remove www from my url and force https and remove .html all at the same time?

```
RewriteEngine on

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# Remove .html
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule     ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `.htacces` instead of your code above.

```
RewriteEngine on

#Force HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Start rewrite.
RewriteBase /

# Load page without extension.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

# 301 While Rewrite.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Handle Trailing Slashes.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R,L]

# Rewrite rule to add .html extension back internally.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1.html
```

This will result in **http://www.example.com/test.html** to be handled by the browser as **https://example.com/test** while still loading the `test.html` file.

Comment: any chance you can explain what everything does? also will this still work if i enter website without "www" ?

Comment: tested it with xampp but getting "Your connection is not private" in google chrome

Comment: Yes, this also works if you go to the site without the **www**. Do you have XAMPP setup to handle HTTPS connections? That message will show up if you didn't set it up properly, or don't have a certificate.

Comment: tried it on my real site seem to have the same problem. could it be because im using a sub domain?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at `.htaccess` in main directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R]

#the code above will redirect the entire site into https without www unless the request come with https://www .      

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R]

#The code above will catch any request with www if passed first code.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

#the code above will remove any .HTML.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# you can use the two lines if file without extension not work and you want to map them to .html files and if you want to go the same file .html without extension keep it as it is but , If you want to change it to same name .php file , replace $.html in the last line to $.php .
```